# Importing own module gives error: packages are not defined

Tags: python, module

I have a directory that looks as follows:

```
script.py
modules:
     create_engine.py
     otherfunctions.py
```

And in script.py I am importing several functions, such as my_create_engine from create_engine.py by using the code:

```
from modules.create_engine import my_create_engine
```

Where my_create_engine is coded as follows:

```
import sqlalchemy

def my_create_engine(mydsn, mydatabase, **kwargs):
    connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://@%s' % mydsn
    cargs = {'database' : mydatabase}
    cargs.update(**kwargs)
    e = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string, connect_args = cargs)
    return e
```

Importing the function works, but when I call the function I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'sqlalchemy' is not defined.
```

I also get this error message for other functions that I am importing. All required packages' names are not defined.

What am I doing wrong? Also, it does not help if I import these required packages in script.py

So what does work if I define the function in script.py:

```
import sqlalchemy


def my_create_engine(mydsn, mydatabase, **kwargs):

    connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://@%s' % mydsn
    cargs = {'database' : mydatabase}
    cargs.update(**kwargs)
    e = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string, connect_args = cargs)
    return e


engine = my_create_engine('dablab_connect', '2021_EXP')
```

Comment: what is the full traceback error? in which line does it happen?

Comment: It happens in line 167:

engine = my_create_engine('dablab_connect', '2021_EXP') 

I am using RStudio with Python, and I do not get a full traceback error somehow.

Comment: Could it be that you wrote sqlalchemy.create_engine once and alter changed it to sql? Python then might not have reloaded your file and still uses the old version. Verify that the command matches your input & retry after restarting python.